# Can seam 2.0.2 application work on Jboss eap 6?

Tags: jboss, migration, wildfly, seam

We are working on migration our application from Jboss server 4 to Jboss eap6.
In this application we have used seam 2.0.2 jars and on migration lots of exception are coming related to seam.Can anyone tell if this is not compatibility issue?And do we need to upgrade our seam jars as well?
Below exception is also coming for Jboss eap 6.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Jboss\ComparingServerInternetJboss\Internet-Jboss-5\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\ABCDEF.ear\jboss-seam-2.0.2.SP1.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:215)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:145)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:159)
            at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handleArchiveByFile(URLScanner.java:111)
            at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.handle(URLScanner.java:98)
            at org.jboss.seam.deployment.URLScanner.scanResources(URLScanner.java:81)
            at org.jboss.seam.deployment.StandardDeploymentStrategy.scan(StandardDeploymentStrategy.java:67)

Comment: Please share your relevant code and the exceptions as well.

Comment: from the path it looks like it is an exception from jboss 5 not Jboss 6

Comment: Have a look at the Windup migration tool - windup.jboss.org. It might give you some hint.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this??